# Why does the potential of both power supplies drop when only one is needed to maintain the current?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

In the circuit shown above, the current through the ammeter is the sum of the currents through each power supply. By Kirchoff‘s Voltage Law however, we can treat each power supply to be in an individual loop with the resistor and ammeter connection and the sum of the potential differences is equivalent to the EMF across each supply. This implies that both power supplies are providing the potential drop to maintain current through the ammeter and resistor connection which doesn’t seem logical; why would they both drop in potential to maintain the current through the central connection when, by Kirchoff’s Voltage Law, we calculate each power supply as though capable of maintaining the current in the connection alone? Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> the current through the ammeter is the sum of the currents through each power supply.

That's true. But maybe not for the reason you think. I believe that the ammeter will read 3/12 A. But I also believe that the current through the 20V source will be 3/12 A, while the current through the 10V source will be zero.

> we can treat each power supply [...separately...]

Yes, but the way to do that is to "null out" the other power supply–set its voltage to zero. A constant zero-volt source is the same as a piece of wire. You null out a power supply by *shorting* it out.

When you null out the left-hand power supply, the remainder of the circuit looks like this

```
          +---/\/\/\/---+---/\/\/\---+
          |             |            |
          |             \            |
          |             /            |
          |             \           ---
          |             /         -------
          |             \            .
          |             /            .
          |             |           ---
          |             |         -------
          |             A            |
          |             |            |
          +-------------+------------+
```

Do the math, and you'll see that the 10V supply drives 1/12 of an ampere through the ammeter (A).

Do the same for the other power supply, and you'll see that it drives 2/12 of an ampere through the ammeter. Those numbers add up to 3/12 A.

You can also add up the currents due to each power supply through any other component. That's called the [*superposition principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle), and it is applicable here because resistors and voltage sources are strictly linear components.

If you add up the currents through the 10V source due to its own action (when the 20V source is "nulled out"), and due to the 20V source (when the 10V source is nulled out), then I think you will find that the current in that branch of the circuit is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response, your breakdown of the circuit into two shorted circuits, each with one power supply, has helped. What I still don't understand is how, when using Kirchoff's Voltage Law, we can always claim that 40I2 + 40I1 = 20 where I2 is current through the ammeter and I1 current through the power supply. How do the equations always add up consistently to account for both power supplies?